# Using Selenium to scrape twitter followers

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Very new to coding, and I am trying to scrape Twitter followers using Seleniunm with this code

this is the login code which works fine

```
#hope this works

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

username = "user"
password = "password"


options=Options()
webdriver_service = Service(r'c:\Users\DeathCraft\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
actions = ActionChains(webdriver_service)

driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(username)
sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div').click()
sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input').send_keys(password)
sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div').click()
sleep(2)
```

*after logging in

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/user/followers")
sleep(2)

follower_list = []

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
sleep(1)
new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
sleep(1)
print("looping")

while last_height != new_height:
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(1)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    
else:
    print("Done Scrolling :D")
    sleep(1)
    print("starting scan")
    usernames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0')
    print("css selected")
    print(usernames)
    sleep(3)
    print("going in")
    for username in usernames:
        username = username.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0").get_property("innerText")
        print("I got one!:")
        print(username)
        if username not in follower_list:
            follower_list.append(username)

print(len(follower_list))
print("almost there")
print(follower_list)
print("astounding success")
```

I am extremely stuck with trying to get the program to find the elements containing the @username and have no idea how it works to use XPATH to grab multiple similar things.

Using class name spits out nothing
using xpath leads to a bunch of errors, or grabs only 1 user, and i dont know how to make it grab all the different usernames, the xpath for each of the blocks are

//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]

//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]

//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[3]

Dived through dozens of posts tryna understand my problem, but to no avail.
how do i get my program to understand :(

Comment: Have you checked any posts using the web scraping tag?

Comment: far too many :(

Comment: learn more about Xpath or CSSselector, get elements for type of element and attributes likes class or id

Answer (score 0):

In your case xpath selector would be like

```
//*[@data-testid='UserCell']//a//span//span[string-length(text()) > 0]
```

Probably there can be better way to identify user name, but most of elements inside user cell don't have unique attributes, just general class references.